# Как можно создать приложение с голосовым управлением?

Tags: c#, распознавание-речи

Ну чтобы программа работала под конкретные команды. Например: "Выключать комп", "свернуть окно" и т.д. Чтобы я говорил и он под голосовую команду выполнял. Просто опишите методы, потом что нужно знать для этого. Буду любезен подробностям. ЯП - C#

Answer (score 1):

Голосовое управление в Windows можно сделать с помощью [SpeechRecognitionEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx). Подход такой:

- добавляете поддержку распознавания речи в приложение,
- добавляете распознавание конкретный речевых образцов - команд,
- вешаете на обработчик события распознавания анализатор команд,
- при совпадении речевого ввода с речевой командой выполняете нужное действие.

Пример на API: [Voice Command](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11771/Voice-Command).

Comment: Действительно, все очень просто!